# Float left div staying at bottom of page

Tags: css, html

I've been banging my head on this on for a while now and I'm just stumped.  Basically I have a left nav bar and then I want the main content just to the right of this, but no matter what I try the main content is at the bottom of the page.

Here is the section of code for the page.

```html
<div class="leftnav">
<?php require_once('includes/leftnav.php'); ?>
 </div>
<div class="mainContent">
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])) { ?>
  Welcome back <?php echo $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']; ?>.
<p>Here are just a few of your latest stats.</p>
<table width="500" border="1">
 <tr>
  <td scope="col">Most recent show total:</td>
  <th scope="col"><?php echo "$".$row_MostRecent['total_retail']; ?></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Current month shows total:</td>
  <td><?php echo "$".$row_CurrentMonth['CurrentMonth']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Last month shows total:</td>
  <td><?php echo "$".$row_LastMonth['LastMonth']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Year to date shows total:</td>
  <td><?php echo "$".$row_YeartoDate['YeartoDate']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<?php } else { ?>
Alternative text if user is not logged in.
<?php } ?>
</p>
<div class="clearfloat"></div>
</div>
```

Now here is the CSS code for these specific divs listed above.

```css
.leftnav {
height: auto;
width: 25%;
border: 1px #000 solid;
float:left;
}
.mainContent {
float: left;
width: 70%;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 0;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 0;
}

.clearfloat { 
clear:both;
height:0;
font-size: 1px;
line-height: 0px;
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me figure out where I have gone wrong with this.  Just as a little additional information, I'm using Dreamweaver CS5 for this site.  Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Here is the HTML/CSS code from the leftnav.php include file.

```html
 <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) { ?>
 <div id="login">
 Please login below:
 <form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" method="POST">
<p>
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input name="username" type="text" id="username" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input name="password" type="password" id="password" />
</p>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
 </p>
 </form>
 <?php } else { ?>
 <?php echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']  . "!"; ?>
 <br />
 <a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Log out</a>
 <?php } ?>
 <p>Upcoming shows: </p>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])) { ?>
<table class="upcoming" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="50%" scope="col">Hostess</th>
    <th width="50%" scope="col">Date/Time</th>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_UpcomingShows['hostess_fname'] . " " . $row_UpcomingShows['hostess_lname']; ?> </td>
      <td><?php $date = date_create($row_UpcomingShows['actual_datetime']); echo date_format($date, 'D M j Y'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_UpcomingShows = mysql_fetch_assoc($UpcomingShows)); ?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
<p><br />
  Newest daughters:
  <br />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The padding on your `.mainContent` div might be a problem. (It will effectively make the width wider than 70%).

Comment: Rendered HTML output please. This is a HTML/CSS question, not a PHP one!

Comment: Create a fiddle with your HTML/CSS defective! :)

Comment: I just created a fiddle with your code and it seems fine.. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MQmEB/) May be the inclusion of the php code in the `<div class="leftnav">`is altering the view.

Answer (score 0):

Your width adds up to more than 100% of the screen. You are utilizing 95% + unspecified `.leftnav` and `.maincontent` margins + the default padding on `.leftnav`. Specify `0px` padding and margins and there is no problem.